# sending email from oracle 12c proc

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

i am trying to send emails from oracle 12c from a stored procedure ,but i get some errors when i compile it.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE email_alert as

  l_mail_host  VARCHAR2(50) := 'smtp.companyname.com';
  l_from       VARCHAR2(50) := 'email';
  l_to         VARCHAR2(50) := 'email';
BEGIN
  UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => l_from,
                recipients => l_to,
                subject    => 'AUTOMATED_EMAIL_ALERT_10G (MYSID): Success',
                message    => 'AUTOMATED_EMAIL_ALERT_10G (MYSID) completed
successfully!');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => l_from,
                  recipients => l_to,
                  subject    => 'AUTOMATED_EMAIL_ALERT_10G (MYSID): Error',
                  message    => 'AUTOMATED_EMAIL_ALERT_10G (MYSID) failed with the
following error:' || SQLERRM);
END email_alert;
```

when i complie the above procedure it gives error as

```
: PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_MAIL.SEND' must be declared. what am i missing here?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have install UTL_MAIL Package in your database. Follow the below steps. Hope this helps you.

- Go to your Oracle Home directory and navigate to the path  `rdbms > admin`. For example `C:\ProgramFiles\OracleXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin`
- Connect to SQLPLUS from that path and run `@utlmail.sql` and `@prvtmail.plb` packages
- After creating the packages, grant execute permission as shown below if required to the DB user 
  `GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_MAIL TO <DB_USER>;`
- Make sure ACL is created for the host if not create as shown below (ACL creation code for 12c or above) and retry your procedure again.Provide host and principal_name in the below code block.Lower and Upper Ports if required. Default port for Mail server is 25.

  `begin 
   dbms_network_acl_admin.append_host_ace( 
      host=>'<example.com>', 
      lower_port=>25, --port if required or NULL 
      upper_port=>25, --port if required or NULL 
      ace=>xs$ace_type(privilege_list =>xs$name_list('connect','resolve'), 
                       principal_name=>'<DB_USER>', 
                       principal_type =>xs_acl.ptype_db)); 
   END;`

Comment: use `select * from all_procedures where object_type='PACKAGE'  and object_name='UTL_MAIL'` query and check

Comment: 24247. 00000 -  "network access denied by access control list (ACL)"
          *Cause:    No access control list (ACL) has been assigned to the target
           host or the privilege necessary to access the target host has not
           been granted to the user in the access control list.@ahamed

Comment: You have to create ACL for your mail server. Provide host and principal_name in the below code block and Lower and Upper Ports if required. Default port for Mail server is 25                                          
  `begin
dbms_network_acl_admin.append_host_ace(
   host=>'<example.com>',
   lower_port=>25, --port if required or NULL
   upper_port=>25, --port if required or NULL
   ace=>xs$ace_type(privilege_list =>xs$name_list('connect','resolve'),
        principal_name=>'<DB_USER>',
        principal_type =>xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
`

Comment: i am able to send email but the body and subject are empty@ahamed